# CSS transform blurs the checkbox on Firefox 41.0.1

Tags: css, firefox, checkbox, css-transforms

When I use `transform` on a check box, the checkbox becomes blurry.

### Without css transform

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check"><span> Check me</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

### With css transform

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check"><span> Check me</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

What is the cause of the issue and how can it be resolved?

Comment: It is because of sub-pixel rendering. A `transform: translate3d(-53%, -53%, 0);` with `top: 53%; left: 53%;` would help make the checkbox clearer.

Comment: @Abhitalks Thank you, it looks clearer now. If you add it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Note that I test in a Mac and there is no issue.

Comment: @Muhammet: This is still a hack and I would not consider this as a solution. The problem is because of the percentages when converted to matrix result in decimal pixels and sub-pixel rendering then blurs it. Am yet to find a solution, hence offered a quick hack.

Comment: @Abhitalks Thank you again for the explanation.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yeah, I am on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I assume it, but I tell you only as a note that you can consideer. In Mac Book Pro with MacOS Capitan all is fine

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Got it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the browsers default focus state you are seeing. You can disable this by overriding the state. `element:focus{outline:none;}`

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the problem. Tried removing the outline, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because it's wrapped in the label. If you don't need the clickable label do this to get around it:

```
<div class="box">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check"><label for="check">Check me</label>
</div>
```

You could add a little js to select the checkbox when the label is clicked. I couldn't find a way around this with css.

Comment: You html code is not correct. The for property in the label is meant to be used to link with an id not the name property.